# Error with SELECT CASE with regular expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I wrote the following query in T-SQL for SQL Server

```
SELECT 
   CASE
      WHEN ADDR_LINE_1 REGEXP '^[0-9]'
      THEN SUBSTRING(ADDR_LINE_1,1,CHARINDEX(' ',ADDR_LINE_1))
      ELSE NULL
   END AS HOUSE_NUMBER
FROM CUSTOMER
```

What I want is that if the column ADDR_LINE_1 starts with a number, I want to extract the HOUSE_NUMBER from it.  But right now my query gives a parse error.  If I replace the word REGEXP with LIKE, the parse error goes away, but I always get NULL for HOUSE_NUMBER.  What is the correct syntax for my query?

Comment: What is your MS SQL Server version? As far as I know MS SQL Server doesn't support Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ISNUMERIC` and `LEFT` like this.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(ADDR_LINE_1, 1)) = 1 
    THEN SUBSTRING(ADDR_LINE_1, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', ADDR_LINE_1))
    ELSE NULL 
    END AS HOUSE_NUMBER
FROM CUSTOMER
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using the LIKE

```
SELECT 
   CASE
      WHEN ADDR_LINE_1 Like '%[0-9]%'
      THEN SUBSTRING(ADDR_LINE_1,1,CHARINDEX(' ',ADDR_LINE_1))
      ELSE NULL
   END AS HOUSE_NUMBER
FROM CUSTOMER
```

Comment: This ended up helping me `WHEN ADDR_LINE_1 Like '[0-9]%'`

Comment: Even better.   You also may want to consider ParseName()